# Handling errors in java script

Tags: javascript, backend, http-status-code-500

I have problem in JavaScript when it comes handling errors. This is the code:

```
    const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
  const {user} = useContext(Context);

  const handleSubmit = async (e, resp) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    const newPost = {
      username:user.username,
      title,
      desc,
    };
    if(file){
      const data = new FormData();
      const filename = Date.now() + file.name;
      data.append("name", filename);
      data.append("file",file);
      newPost.photo = filename;
      try{
        await axios.post("/upload",data);
      }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
    try{
    const res = await axios.post("/posts", newPost);
    window.location.replace("/post/"+res.data._id);
    }catch(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

I am pretty sure that mistake comes from handling errors because I am getting this error:
POST http://localhost:3000/posts 500 (Internal Server Error)
When I handled errors correctly I didn't have this. But now not sure what to write inside catch block so I can get rid of this error.

Comment: http://localhost:3000/posts 500 (Internal Server Error) the error seems to be coming from Backend your code seems fine? Are you running backend server on your local machine? Can you see backend console for error?

Comment: The error is coming from the server. Check you are sending a valid request, then diagnose the issue at the server.

Comment: "When I handled errors correctly" What does that mean. What is not correct with how it is not working currently?

Comment: For backend I get this error:Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: So you need to figure out what the backend code is doing that it has a 404. My guess is you did not set up the proxy correctly with Axios

Comment: Proxy is OK, because this is the first time I am getting this error for this project

Comment: Is there other way to concate id of post in window.location.replace function? Maybe there is the problem